# Plain Javascript unbind document event

Tags: javascript, delegates, dom-events

I have difficulties with event listeners and unbinding them.
I have the following code:

```
function delegate(el, evt, sel, handler) {
    el.addEventListener(evt, function(event) {
        var t = event.target;
        while (t && t !== this) {
            if (t.matches(sel)) {
                handler.call(t, event);
            }
            t = t.parentNode;
        }
    });
}
```

And I apply the function like this:

```
function captureMouseDown() {
    console.log('mouse downed');
}

delegate(document, 'mousedown', '.js-flex', captureMouseDown);
```

How do I undelegate the event on the document and/or the selector js-flex

Comment: you can use `removeEventListener`

Answer (score 1):

One option is to have `delegate` return the function passed to `addEventListener`, and then you can call `removeEventListener` with it:

```
function delegate(el, evt, sel, handler) {
    const listener = function(event) {
        var t = event.target;
        while (t && t !== this) {
            if (t.matches(sel)) {
                handler.call(t, event);
            }
            t = t.parentNode;
        }
    };
    el.addEventListener(evt, listener);
    return listener;
}

const listener = delegate(document, 'mousedown', '.js-flex', captureMouseDown);
// ...
document.removeEventListener('mousedown', listener);
```